# D3.js scaleLinear is not returning the correct output for 0 value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js, frontend

I'm using d3js to draw some graphs in my awesome UI, here below the scales I'm calling.

```
import {ScaleLinear, scaleLinear } from 'd3';
```

Given the scale I have created below

```
const history = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
const maxValue = Math.max(...history);
const localYScale: ScaleLinear<number, number> = scaleLinear().domain([0, maxValue]).range([0, 32]);
```

by calling `localYScale(0)` I would expect the returned value to be `0` but it's returning `16`...

I did few tweaks to investigate and turns out that if I assign a fallback value that is very close from 0 the `localYScale(0)` method returns the expected value for some reasons...

```
const maxValue = Math.max(...history) || 0,001;
```

I'm I missing something here with `d3`?....
Thanks

Comment: FWIW, your domain and your scale in general don't seem to make any sense. What's the meaning of scaling a zero-width domain to any non-zero range? As it is, your code works as expected, at least when looking at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/main/src/continuous.js#L15) of the `normalize()` function: `return (b -= (a = +a)) ? function(x) { return (x - a) / b; } : constant(isNaN(b) ? NaN : 0.5);`. If `a` equals `b` it defaults to 0.5 returning the middle of your range which is 16.

Comment: Hey @altocumulus, thanks for the reply...
I don't get exactly why you think that my scale doesn't make sense, the goal to achieve is to draw a barChart, the bars must be able to span accordingly given that the bar with the highest value shouldn't exceed the height of 32px which is represented by the `range([0, 32])`

Comment: @altocumulus the graph seems to work properly but for some reason, it's only failing when the values inside the history array are all 0 and the `domain([0, 0])` kinda behave differently...

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to tell you. To have any bars in the first place you got to have at least one non-zero value in your domain. A scale maps the domain's interval onto the range's interval. What would you expect it to return if the domain was a zero-width interval? Why should that be returning the lower bound of the range instead of the mean? Your scenario of an all-zero domain is a rather exceptional case that requires exceptional handling. So, your safeguard of defaulting lo any non-zero value is a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: Furthermore, since there won't be any bars if you have an all-zero domain you could shortcut the drawing of the bars in that case altogether and decide to not draw them at all.

Comment: @altocumulus Fair enough, thanks for your dedication and time  